# java.io.FileNotFoundException some_path XXXXX (The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect)

Tags: java, logging, log4j

I use `-Dlog4j.configuration=file:C:\repo\application\logs\log4j.properties` for the POJO to load Log4J.properties configuration and look for file appender, pretty much the configuration is like this:

```
log4j.logger.com.domain.app.myclass=DEBUG, FILEAPPENDER
log4j.appender.FILEAPPENDER=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.FILEAPPENDER.Encoding=UTF-8
log4j.appender.FILEAPPENDER.File==C:/Logs/app_debug.log
log4j.appender.FILEAPPENDER.MaxFileSize=10000KB
log4j.appender.FILEAPPENDER.MaxBackupIndex=10
log4j.appender.FILEAPPENDER.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.FILEAPPENDER.layout.ConversionPattern=%d -- %p -- %c -- %m%n
```

and I got

```
log4j:ERROR setFile(null,true) call failed.
java.io.FileNotFoundException: =C:\Logs\app_debug.log (The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect)
```

I thought it was typo, but this is not the case. And permission issue? No matter what directory I change, it always gives me `java.io.FileNotFoundException some_path_XXXXX (The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect)`

what did I miss?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure what `==` mean in this line `log4j.appender.FILEAPPENDER.File==C:/Logs/app_debug.log`

It should be `log4j.appender.FILEAPPENDER.File=C:/Logs/app_debug.log`